# Django - Retrieve a session value to a form

Tags: python, django

I have a Django aplication and need to get a value from the session and put it in a HiddenInput.

I have this code in my view:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def obra_open_view(request, obra_id):
    obra = get_object_or_404(Obra, pk=obra_id)

    if obra:
        request.session['obra_aberta_id'] = obra.id
        request.session['obra_aberta_name'] = obra.nome
        return redirect('obra_detail_url')
    else:
        request.session['obra_aberta_id'] = 0
        request.session['obra_aberta_name'] = ""
        return redirect('obra_lista_url')
```

When I have some value on 'obra_aberta_id' I need to put this value on a HiddenInput:

```
class FormCarga(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Carga
        fields = ('__all__')
        
        widgets = {
            'tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'descricao': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'potencia': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'unidade_medida_potencia': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'area': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'tensao': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'fonte': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'atividade': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'fator_potencia': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'condutores_carregados': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'obra': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','initial' : request.session['obra_aberta_id']}),

        }
```

But I'm getting an error on 'request': name 'request' is not defined

How can I get a value from the session e set os this HiddenInput?

I don't know if the models will help, but there it is anyway:

```
class Carga(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descricao = models.TextField(blank=True,
                                verbose_name='Descrição')
    potencia = models.CharField(blank=True,
                                max_length=10,
                                verbose_name='Potência')
    unidade_medida_potencia = models.ForeignKey(UnidadeMedidaPotencia,
                                                on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                                null=True,
                                                blank=True,
                                                verbose_name='Unidade de Medida')
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area,
                            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                            null=True,
                            verbose_name='Área')    
    tensao = models.ForeignKey(Tensao,
                                on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                null=True,
                                verbose_name='Tensão')
    fonte = models.ForeignKey(Fonte,
                            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                            null=True)
    atividade = models.ForeignKey(Atividade,
                                on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                null=True)

    fator_potencia = models.ForeignKey(FatorPotencia,
                                        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                        null=True,
                                verbose_name='Fator de Potência')
    condutores_carregados = models.ForeignKey(CondutoresCarregados,
                                            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                            null=True)
    obra = models.ForeignKey(Obra,
                            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                            null=False)

class Obra(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.TextField(blank=True,
                                verbose_name='Descrição')  # opcional
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                            blank=True)
    revisao = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                blank=True,
                                verbose_name='Revisão')  # opcional
    descricao_revisao = models.TextField(blank=True,
                                        verbose_name='Descrição da Revisão')
    bloqueado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Se o externo for apagado, não apaga a obra
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(PessoaJuridica,
                                on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                null=True)
    participantes = models.ManyToManyField(PessoaFisica,
                                        through='FuncaoPessoaObra')
    contato = models.ManyToManyField(Contato)

    # (equivalente ao tostring) aparecer o nome no site admin
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Edit:

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block titulo %}
  {{ nome_pagina }}
{% endblock %}

{% block conteudo %} 

  {% include 'parciais/_messages.html' %}

  <h1 class="mt-3 mb-3">
    {{ nome_pagina }}
  </h1>
  
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% if editavel %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Salvar</button>
      {% else %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="{% url url_lista %}">Lista</a>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
    </br>

{% endblock %}
```

And here is the view where I will use it:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def carga_new_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = FormCarga(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Carga cadastrada com sucesso!')

            # Redirect para a lista de cargas
            return redirect('carga_list_url')
    else:
        form = FormCarga()
        nome_pagina = 'Nova Carga'

    page_dictionary = {
        'form': form,
        'nome_pagina': nome_pagina,
        'editavel': True,
        'url_lista': 'carga_list_url',
    }

    return render(request, 'item.html', page_dictionary)
```

Comment: you can add value to widget on the render. Or you can render field in template yourself, or you can add initial data to formField. Can you provide view code and template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove from `obra` widget initial dict.

```
class FormCarga(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Carga
        widgets = {
            'obra': forms.HiddenInput(),
            # other staff
        }
```

After that you can do:

```
def carga_new_view(request):
    initial={'obra': request.session.get('obra_aberta_id')}
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = FormCarga(request.POST, initial=initial)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Carga cadastrada com sucesso!')

            # Redirect para a lista de cargas
            return redirect('carga_list_url')
    else:
        form = FormCarga(initial=initial)
        nome_pagina = 'Nova Carga'

    page_dictionary = {
        'form': form,
        'nome_pagina': nome_pagina,
        'editavel': True,
        'url_lista': 'carga_list_url',
    }

    return render(request, 'item.html', page_dictionary)
```

But PLEASE read about Django-GCBV FormView. In your case:

```
class CargaNewView(FormView):
    template = 'item.html'
    success_url = 'carga_list_url'
    form_class = FormCarga

    def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_initial(*args, **kwargs) | {'obra': request.session['obra_aberta_id']}

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs) | {'nome_pagina': 'Nova Carga', 'editavel': True, 'url_lista': self.success_url}
```

I pass, your have a ModelForm. In this case you can use Django-GCBV EditView.

Comment: It works. Thaks! I'll read about "Django-GCBV FormView"